# How to split a repeat count of a value in a list and display the actual values?

Tags: python, list

A repetitive value in my list is being displayed as '99*0.00' which represents 99 times the value of 0.00. I want to convert my list to an array and display these repetitive counts as actual values.

I have tried building an if loop but without success.

```
my_list = ['99*0.00', '24.93', '24.91', '24.92', '5*24.98','25.00', '305*1.00',
 '25.04', '25.02', '24.94', '24.94', '24.94', '24.95']
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what your difficulty is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback. (In other words, show your attempted "if loop" that you mentioned.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a function that can expand an element into a list of repeated values

```
def expand(s):
    if '*' in s:
        repeat, value = s.split('*')
        return [value for _ in range(int(repeat))]
    else:
        return [s]
```

Then call this on each element, and flatten the resulting list

```
import itertools
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(expand(s) for s in my_list))
```

This results in

```
['0.00', '0.00', '0.00', ..., '24.93', '24.91', '24.92', '24.98', '24.98', '24.98', '24.98', '24.98', '25.00', '1.00', '1.00', '1.00', ..., '25.04', '25.02', '24.94', '24.94', '24.94', '24.95']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for s in my_list:
    if '*' in s:
        n,x = s.split('*')
        for i in range(int(n)):
            print(x)
    else:
        print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like that to get result with number values:

```
my_list = ['99*0.00', '24.93', '24.91', '24.92', '5*24.98','25.00', '305*1.00',
 '25.04', '25.02', '24.94', '24.94', '24.94', '24.95']


new_list = []
for item in my_list:
    if '*' in item:
        first, second = item.split('*')
        value = float(first) * float(second)
    else:
        value = float(item)
    new_list.append(value)

print(new_list)

[0.0,
 24.93,
 24.91,
 24.92,
 124.9,
 25.0,
 305.0,
 25.04,
 25.02,
 24.94,
 24.94,
 24.94,
 24.95]
```